# WebLogic 11G: Deleted WARs Still Being Listed

Tags: weblogic11g

WebLogic 11G
Windows XP

Hi,

I'm running WebLogic 11g. I put two WARs into the autodeploy directory. Everything was fine. A few months later I no longer needed them so I deleted them from the autodeploy directory.

When I log into the WebLogic 11g Admin site, those WARs are still listed as being there under "deployments". If I try to delete those listing through the admin site I get told that since they were autodeployed they have to be manually deleted from the directory. Which I did, in addition to restarting WebLogic 11g and I even tried stopping the services first. No dice.

How can I fix this?

Thanks much in advance

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you shutdown your WLS server, open the domain config.xml in the text editor and search for all the  tag. Very likely you will see  section regarding those war files that you deleted. Remove these  sections. Then start your WLS again.